# Vue.Js 2 Input formatting number

Tags: input, vuejs2, numbers, format, vue-component

I have been struggling to get a number input to format numbers using vuejs2.

Migrating some view logic from asp.net core 2 to vue and I was using this:

```
<input asp-for="Model.LoanAmount" value="@(Model.LoanAmount > 0 ? Model.LoanAmount.ToString("N2") : String.Empty)" >
```

but that required me to reload that view onchange of the input.

I need a way to format number inputs with US format and 2 decimal places, (1,000,000.21) but to display nothing when the model value is zero or empty.
vue-numeric does **ALMOST** everything, but fails for me when I try to use a placeholder.

```
<vue-numeric v-model="vm.loanAmount" seperator="," placeholder=" " :precision="2" ></vue-numeric>
```

I tried using a space for placeholder because it crashes when I use an empty string.
This example displays 0.00 if zero or empty is inputted. I tried playing with the **output-type** and **empty-value** props.

I'm not wedded to vue-numeric but it is handy because I don't know of a more convenient solution.

Comment: Try out [vue-cleave-component](https://github.com/ankurk91/vue-cleave-component)
It has so many options, including currency

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve the formatting by simply using a `computed` property with separate `getter` and `setter` without the need for other dependencies.

```
computed: {
  formattedValue: {
    get: function() {
      return this.value;
    },
    set: function(newValue) {
      if (newValue.length > 2) {
        newValue = newValue.replace(".", "");
        this.value =
          newValue.substr(0, newValue.length - 2) +
          "." +
          newValue.substr(newValue.length - 2);
      } else {
        this.value = newValue;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/p7j447k7wq

I only added the decimal separator as an example, you'll have to add the `,` thousand separator in the setter for your full functionality.

Comment: I followed this advice but it doesn't do exactly what I need,  computed property setter sets immediately), I need something that will only format on `change` of the input. I also found the handy `Number.prototype.toLocaleString()` method built in to js. For now I am using a method because idk a way to get computed property to only update on `change` event

Comment: You can't get a computed property to only update on change, the entire point of a computed value is to reflect _any_ change in the values it depends/computes on. You can however simply call your formatting as a method call on `change` (i.e. don't use a computed property, use a method to format and a simple `v-model`).